# Mocked Rest template is returning a null response

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito

I am new to JUnit5 and Mockito framework in springboot. Here I am trying to mock the RestTemplate and return a 200 status with a string response. But I am getting a null response and the function throws a Null Pointer Exception. Is there any mistake in the way I am mocking the rest template?

**Service**

```
public class Abc {
  
  @Autowired
  RestTemplate template;

  @Value("${ser.url}")
  String url;

   void validate(String val){
       
       ResponseEntity<String> response;
       try{
            response = template.postForEntity(url, HTTP_ENTITY, String.class);

       } catch(Exception ex ){
             .....
       }     
        sysout(response); //Prints Null

        String res = response.getBody(); //Null Pointer exception
  }
}
```

**Testing**

```
class ServiceTest {

    @InjectMocks
    Abc abc; 

    @Mock
    RestTemplate template;

    @BeforeEach
    void setup(){
        MockitoAnnotations.init(this);
    }
 
    @Test
    void testIt(){
        when(template.postForEntity(anyString(), any(), ArgumentMatchers.<Class<String>>any())).
              thenReturn(new ResponseEntity<String>("value",HttpStatus.OK));
        
        abc.validate("abc"); 
    }
}
```

Comment: In your mock, change the third argument passed to postForEntity to eq(String.class)

Comment: @Yayotrón I tried it, doesn't work. Still returns null

Comment: You're using @Mock in your class, this annotation only works in unit test. You need to expect an actual instance in your class. Try changing your code in Abc to receive the RestTemplate through the constructor, and then in your test initialize new Abc(template) instead of using @ InjectMocks. I think that should do it

Comment: Why is RestTemplate in ABC annotated with `@Mock`

Comment: sorry thats a typo. Real implementation its not there.. Its Autowired

Comment: I see. Well if you're getting null in your call to what should be mocked the possibilities are either you're not using the mock that you think are using (it wasn't injected) o your mock is receiving the wrong arguments. Either way you can easily verify which one is the case by using the debugger and a breakpoint.

Comment: the problem, I found out. Here I am using @Value to get the URL. Instead, if I am hardcoding the value of the URL, the test case return success. Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

After long time experiments in the past I have realized that @InjectMocks sometimes works not as expected. So now I make use of @MockBean instead. This code works:

```
@Service    
public class Abc {
    @Autowired
    RestTemplate template;

    @Value("${ser.url}")
    String url;

    void validate(String val){

        ResponseEntity<String> response = null;
        try{
            response = template.postForEntity(url, new HttpEntity<>(""),
                    String.class);

        } catch(Exception ex ){
             ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(response); //Prints Null

        String res = response.getBody(); //Null Pointer exception
    }    
}

@SpringBootTest
class AbcTest {

    @Autowired
    Abc abc;

    @MockBean
    RestTemplate template;    

    @Test
    void testIt(){
        when(template.postForEntity(anyString(), any(), ArgumentMatchers.<Class<String>>any())).
                thenReturn(new ResponseEntity<String>("value", HttpStatus.OK));

        abc.validate("abc");
    }
}
```